# How to play mp3 in python without opening any new window

Tags: python

I want to play mp3 files without opening it in a new window
For example:- vlc module opens a new window to play files
and I don't want this to happen.. I was expecting it to play it without opening a new window... Any solutions?

Comment: How do you run your python in the first place? Command line? Jupyter? IDE?

Comment: I run my code in an IDE.. 
When I use pygame i get an error :-
"pygame.error: Failed loading libmpg123-0.dll: The specified module could not be found."

Answer (score 2):

You can play mp3 files without opening it in a new window in several ways:
You can also use `pygame` module:

```
import pygame
import time

pygame.mixer.init()

pygame.mixer.music.load('music.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play()
print("Audio will play for 4 seconds")

time.sleep(4)
```

or, using `playsound` module

```
from playsound import playsound
music = 'music.mp3'
playsound(music)
```

Comment: Hi can I avoid the delay after I run the file. My program focuses on precision

Comment: do you mean execution time?

Comment: Yes i meant execution time

Comment: I need to pause and play the sounds too so I cant use playsound

Comment: sorry, there is no method to stop/ pause sound in playsound. I will update my answer as soon as I find another working way.